# react-native-twilio-video-webrtc ios pods error

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods, react-native-ios

I'm building a React-Native app using [react-native-twilio-video-webrtc](https://github.com/blackuy/react-native-twilio-video-webrtc) and I'm having trouble configuring the iOS app with pods. I followed the integration steps for iOS given in the tutorial (link above) and got this error when running pod install :

> Error :
>
> [!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:
>
> TwilioVideo (>= 1.0.1) required by react-native-twilio-video-webrtc (1.0.2)
>       Specs satisfying the TwilioVideo (>= 1.0.1) dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

My environment :
Node 8.1.4,
React Native 0.47.1,
iOS 9.0

My Podfile :

```
target 'MyProject' do

  target 'MyProjectTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end

  pod 'Yoga', path: '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/Yoga.podspec'
  pod 'React', path: '../node_modules/react-native'
  pod 'react-native-twilio-video-webrtc', path: '../node_modules/react-native-twilio-video-webrtc'

end

target 'MyProject-tvOS' do

  target 'MyProject-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it, I just had to set these two lines at the top of my Podfile :

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!
```

Now everything is compiling fine.